# Calculation of transconductance in a MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, transconductance

I am teaching electronics.  I have come across this formula for drain current in the syllabus that I am teaching.  However, I have never seen it before.  My question is where is this number -3 from and is it even correct?

I<sub>d</sub> = G<sub>m</sub> · (V<sub>gs</sub> - 3)

You can take a look at this [syllabus](https://www.eduqas.co.uk/media/vevdmoka/eduqas-a-level-electronics-spec-from-2017-e.pdf) - it's on page 15.

Comment: In the linked document, the formula under discussion is on page 15, (for MOSFET).

Comment: The formula cannot be correct. At first the expression (Vgs-3) is garbage . Secondly, there must be a quadratic relationship between Id and Vgs.

Comment: Thank you for confirming this.

Comment: Have a look at Q9 on this exam paper:  https://pastpapers.download.wjec.co.uk/O20/o20-5490-01.pdf

Comment: And now look at the solution on P15 of the mark scheme:  https://pastpapers.download.wjec.co.uk/A20/a20-C490UA0-1-ms.pdf

Comment: @LvW I have contacted the exam board and they say this: You can approximate Gm to use this formula:   Gm = Id / (Vgs-Vth) and therefore you can assume that typically Vth is 3v giving the formula Id= Gm(Vgs-3).  What do think of this?

Comment: I must admit that I have never seen the approximation Gm=Id/(Vgs-Vth). From this expression I would derive that Gm approaches infinite for Vgs=Vth.  I think, this clearly shows that something must be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For saturation region, and ignoring \$\lambda\$ effects, let

$$Id = \frac{\beta}{2}(Vgs-Vt)^2$$  where $$\beta = (k')(W/L)$$
now taking the partial derivative of \$Id\$ with respect to \$Vgs\$ we get, $$g_{m} = \beta(Vgs-Vt)$$

Since we can isolate \$\beta\$ as $$\beta = \frac{2I_{d}}{(Vgs-Vt)^2}$$

Substitute this \$\beta\$ into \$g_{m}\$ eq. above gives, $$g_{m} = \frac {2I_{d}}{(Vgs-Vt)}$$
then
$$I_{d} = \frac{g_{m}}{2}(Vgs-Vt)$$
If \$V_t=3\$ then $$I_{d} = \frac{g_{m}}{2}(Vgs-3)$$

*from slide p. 15

"(h) define gM as the gradient of an ID-VGS graph."

I am confident it is off by a factor of 1/2, or they will argue that they absorbed the factor somewhere else (inside \$g_m\$ for example).

Comment: But "3" is still missing a unit. It should be "3 V".